# NodeJs MonogoDb: findOneAndUpdate not saving changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The updated results from findOneAndUpdate() return in the console as the request body however the changes are not saved from either my frontend or postman. I have tried quite a few variations but I'm not getting anywhere. Not sure where to go from here. I've done a fair amount of reading but alas not results.

useRoutes.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const User = require("../models/userSchema");

const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

function asyncHandler(callback) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}

//updates user account
router.patch("/user/:id",[
    check("firstName")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "firstName"'),
    check("lastName")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "username"'),
    check("sexualPreference")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "sexualPreference"'),
    check("description")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "description"'),
  ],
  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const errorMessages = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg);
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errorMessages });
    }

    const updateObject = req.body;

    console.log(req.params.id)

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) },{ updateObject }, { new: true }, function(err, doc) {
      if(err) {
          return res.json({success: false, message: err.message});
      }
      console.log(updateObject);
      res.json({ updateObject });

      return res.status(204).end();
    });

  })
);
```

userSchema.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema( {

    firstName:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
   gender:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    sexualPreference: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true 
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    pictures: {
        type: [{
            Object
        }],
    },
    matches: {
        type: [{
            Object
        }],
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `updateObject` as is to the `findOneAndUpdate()` function - instead of wrapping it in another object.

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, updateObject, //...)
```